# SQL Server : custom paging stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, paging, procedure

I have a stored procedure like this:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[zsp_GetUsersAdministratorPanel]
    (@StartRowIndex  INT,
     @MaxRows INT,
     @OrderByField NVARCHAR(200),
     @Asc BIT,
     @SearchValue NVARCHAR(200))
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @UsersTable TABLE(UserId uniqueidentifier,
                              FirstName nvarchar(400),
                              LastName nvarchar(400),
                              Email nvarchar(200)
                             )

    DECLARE @WhereQuery nvarchar(max)

    SET @WhereQuery = ' WHERE '

    IF LEN(@SearchValue) > 0
    BEGIN
        SET @WhereQuery = @WhereQuery +
                  'FirstName like ''%' + @SearchValue + '%''  or '
                + ' LastName like ''%' + @SearchValue + '%''  or '
                + ' Email like ''%' + @SearchValue + '%'''
    END

    DECLARE @OrderQuery nvarchar(max)

    IF LEN(@OrderByField) > 0
    BEGIN
        IF @OrderByField = 'Email'
            SET @OrderQuery = ' ORDER BY Email ' +
                    CASE @Asc WHEN 1 THEN ' ASC ' ELSE ' DESC ' END
        ELSE IF @OrderByField = 'FirstName'
            SET @OrderQuery = ' ORDER BY FirstName ' +  
                    CASE @Asc WHEN 1 THEN ' ASC ' ELSE ' DESC ' END
        ELSE IF @OrderByField = 'LastName'  
            SET @OrderQuery = ' ORDER BY LastName ' +  
                    CASE @Asc WHEN 1 THEN ' ASC ' ELSE ' DESC ' END
    END 

    DECLARE @Query  NVARCHAR(MAX)
    SET @Query = 'select UserId, 
                FirstName,
                LastName,
                Email
            from 
            (
                SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER ('+ @OrderQuery +')
                    AS [ROW_NUMBER], 
                        [t0].[UserId], [t0].[FirstName], 
                        [t0].[LastName], 
                        [t0].[Email]
                        FROM [dbo].[Users] AS [t0]' +
                        @WhereQuery +
            ') AS [t1]' +
                 + ' WHERE [ROW_NUMBER] BETWEEN 
                    @StartRowIndex AND @MaxRows' + @OrderQuery

    PRINT @Query

    INSERT INTO @UsersTable 
        EXEC sp_Executesql @Query,
                    N'@OrderQuery nvarchar(max),
                    @StartRowIndex int,@MaxRows int',
                    @OrderQuery=@OrderQuery,
                    @StartRowIndex = @StartRowIndex,
                    @MaxRows = @MaxRows

    SELECT * FROM @UsersTable           

    SET NOCOUNT OFF;
END
```

When I pass the following parameters:

```
StartRowIndex - 1
MaxRows(page size) - 50
OrderByField - FirstName
Asc - 1
SearchValue - Test
```

I'm getting a following error:

```
select UserId, 
                FirstName,
                LastName,
                Email
            from 
            (


                SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY FirstName  ASC )
                    AS [ROW_NUMBER], 
                        [t0].[UserId], [t0].[FirstName], 
                        [t0].[LastName], 
                        [t0].[Email]
                        FROM [dbo].[Users] AS [t0] WHERE FirstName like '%test%'  or  LastName like '%test%'  or  Email like '%test%') AS [t1] WHERE [ROW_NUMBER] BETWEEN 
                    @StartRowIndex AND @MaxRows ORDER BY FirstName  ASC
```

> Msg 206, Level 16, State 2, Line 4
>   Operand type clash: int is incompatible with uniqueidentifier

I'm not quite sure what is causing the error here... I'm trying to create a stored procedure which would go through my Users test table which will have a large amount of data (500000 users later on), so I'm trying to ensure smooth user experience.

Why am I getting this error?

Can someone help me out?

Comment: What is the type of `UserId’ on `dbo.Users`?

Comment: See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/uniqueidentifier-transact-sql

Comment: @TZHX I declared it as: int identity(1,1) primary key

Comment: @TZHX By the way is this a proper way to go through large collection of data?

Comment: Can you see how that, along with your definition of `@UsersTable` would lead to the error you’ve received?

Comment: @TZHX  Yes I just changed the type to int and it works now ... :D

Comment: And I don’t see what you’re trying to achieve inserting the data to a temp table just to select it? That seems wasteful. If all the sprig is meant to do is select it, just select it.

Comment: @TZHX I thought that It might be easier to just select it from the temp table (how much is defined in the page size) once I filter it out ?

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is that int is not the same type as uniqueidentifier.  These are in fact two different data types.

http://www.sqlteam.com/article/uniqueidentifier-vs-identity

explains that uniqueidentifier is a 16-byte binary value.

```
DECLARE @UsersTable TABLE(UserId uniqueidentifier,
```

should be

```
DECLARE @UsersTable TABLE(UserId int,
```

The comments in response to your question raise other issues with the rest of the procedure, but this addresses specifically the error you have encountered.